# How can I order this list on mathematica?

Tags: matrix, sorting

This is my list

```
Matrix = {{1, -2, 3, -4}, {{a, b}, {f, e}, {a, b}, {f, e}}}
```

I want to order the columns in ascending order depending on the values on the first row.  I Expect something like

```
{{-4, -2, 1, 3}, {{f, e}, {f, e}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}
```

I've tried the `Sort` function, but it just returns the initial value

Comment: Try `Matrix[[All, Ordering[First[Matrix]]]]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Transpose[SortBy[Transpose[Matrix], First]]
```

> {{-4, -2, 1, 3}, {{f, e}, {f, e}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}

```
Transpose[Transpose[#][[Ordering @ First @ #]]] &@ Matrix
```

> {{-4, -2, 1, 3}, {{f, e}, {f, e}, {a, b}, {a, b}}}

Answer (score 3):

Renaming `Matrix` to `myMatrix` (so as to avoid starting a variable name with an upper-case letter):

```
Transpose[
 SortBy[Table[{myMatrix[[1, i]], myMatrix[[2, i]]}, 
   {i, 4}], #[[1]] &]]
```

Comment: Perhaps, you meant `Matrix` instead of `myMatrix`.

Comment: Yes... in my personal code I changed the name because we must never use an upper-case letter to start the name of a variable, lest it conflict with internal definitions.  Thanks.  Solution amended.